# Problems implementing dragging by mouse

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I want to implement a draggable map containing certain elements.

--> See JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7ndx7s25/7/

By use of `mousedown`, `mousemove` and `mouseup` I achieved the dragging.
However I am facing problems:

1. When pressing the mouse button down and then moving outside the window I do not get a `mouseup` event. Reentering the window (having released the mouse button long ago) my map still thinks the button is down and misbehaves accordingly.
2. When there are objects on the map, I do not get `mousemove` events while moving through these objects. Therefore the map hangs and jumps as I enter and leave such an object.
3. While over such objects I still want to have a `move` mouse cursor. I could change the `cursor` style on each object (in the Fiddle I did this for Object 1 as an example), but this doesn't seem like a good way. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Something missing in my answer, or you just haven't found time to check it out?

Comment: @LGSon Didn't found the time to answer :-) Works like a charm. Especially useful was the difference between `mouseout` and `mouseleave` - I didn't know that.

Comment: Thanks ... and great it worked out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need e.g. `mouseout` to catch when leaving the `canvas`, though that event will also fire when the cursor move over the *other elements*.

One easy fix is to simply add a class to `canvas`, that set `pointer-events: none` on those.

*With that class you can control the cursor as well, and avoid setting it with the script.*

Stack snippet

```js
updateInfo = function() {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
    'Position = ' + JSON.stringify(position) +
    '<br />dragInfo = ' + JSON.stringify(dragInfo);
};

const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];

let position = { x: 0, y : 0 };
let dragInfo = null;
updateInfo();

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {  
  dragInfo = {
    startEvent: {
      x: e.clientX,
      y: e.clientY,
    },
    startPosition: position
  };
  canvas.classList.add('dragging');
  updateInfo();
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {  
  if (dragInfo === null) return;
  
  position = {
    x: dragInfo.startPosition.x - (e.clientX - dragInfo.startEvent.x),
    y: dragInfo.startPosition.y - (e.clientY - dragInfo.startEvent.y)
  };
  updateInfo();
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {  
  dragInfo = null;
  canvas.classList.remove('dragging');
  updateInfo();
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
  dragInfo = null;
  canvas.classList.remove('dragging');
  updateInfo();
});
```

```css
* {
  user-select: none;
  font-family: monospace;
}
canvas {
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.dragging {
  cursor: move;
}
.obj {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.dragging ~ .obj {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="myMap-ish">
  <canvas width="500" height="300"></canvas>
  <div class="obj" style="left: 30px; top: 35px">1</div>
  <div class="obj" style="left: 175px; top: 79px">2</div>
  <div class="obj" style="left: 214px; top: 145px">3</div>
  <div class="obj" style="left: 314px; top: 215px">4</div>
</div>
<div id="info"></div>
```

---

Another option could be to use `mouseleave`, on the outer wrapper, the `myMap-ish` element, which could be combined with the above added class to simply cursor handling.

The main difference between `mouseout` and `mouseleave` is that the latter won't fire when hovering children, as shown in below sample, so we don't need to toggle `pointer-events` as we did in the first sample.

*Note, to simply use `mouseleave` in the first sample, on `canvas`, will have the same issue `mouseout` has, since the "other element" aren't children of the `canvas`.*

Stack snippet

```js
updateInfo = function() {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
    'Position = ' + JSON.stringify(position) +
    '<br />dragInfo = ' + JSON.stringify(dragInfo);
};

const canvas = document.getElementById('myMap-ish');

let position = { x: 0, y : 0 };
let dragInfo = null;
updateInfo();

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {  
  dragInfo = {
    startEvent: {
      x: e.clientX,
      y: e.clientY,
    },
    startPosition: position
  };
  canvas.style.cursor = 'move';
  document.querySelectorAll('.obj')[0].style.cursor = 'move'; // TODO for all objects
  updateInfo();
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {  
  if (dragInfo === null) return;
  
  position = {
    x: dragInfo.startPosition.x - (e.clientX - dragInfo.startEvent.x),
    y: dragInfo.startPosition.y - (e.clientY - dragInfo.startEvent.y)
  };
  updateInfo();
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {  
  dragInfo = null;
  canvas.style.cursor = 'default';
  document.querySelectorAll('.obj')[0].style.cursor = 'default';  // TODO for all objects
  updateInfo();
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {  
  dragInfo = null;
  canvas.style.cursor = 'default';
  document.querySelectorAll('.obj')[0].style.cursor = 'default';  // TODO for all objects
  updateInfo();
});
```

```css
* {
  user-select: none;
  font-family: monospace;
}
canvas {
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.obj {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="myMap-ish">
  <canvas width="500" height="300"></canvas>
  <div class="obj" style="left: 30px; top: 35px">1</div>
  <div class="obj" style="left: 175px; top: 79px">2</div>
  <div class="obj" style="left: 214px; top: 145px">3</div>
  <div class="obj" style="left: 314px; top: 215px">4</div>
</div>
<div id="info"></div>
```